# Retrieving the threads and posts giving 403 error in ms graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-groups

In our application there is a requirement to retrieve and display the replies on a threads. When ever we try to retrieve the thread and replies for guest user it gives 403 error for members can retrieve the same without any error. Guest can post a reply to threads without any issue. Below is the endpoint we are using to retrieve the threads with posts

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/<<groupid>>/threads/<<threadId>>?$expand=posts
```

error returned is

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}
```

client-request-id is :

```
80ac411f-bc1d-44dc-b56a-7aec8fb5f98e
```

Comment: How have you acquired the access token used. Also Please add the request id and timestamp